# Javascript implicitly converts type from int to bool while using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So here is the problem, I'm fetching some data from an API and adding it to redux store. The weird part is only for one property in the object being add gets converted from int to bool.

original data

```
{ "iTaskId" : 3 }
```

Data Saved in redux store

```
{ "iTaskId" : true }
```

Im not performing any operations on the data, if I change the property name from "**iTaskId**" to anything else, the data is saved correctly.

has anybody else encountered such a problem before.

**Reducer**

```
const reducer =(state,action) =>{
   switch(action.type){
     case "addtask":return {
          ...state,
         Task:action.payload
      }
   }
}
```

**Action**

```
fetch(url,{
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(objParams),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    credentials: 'same-origin'
}).then(resp=>resp.json())
 .then(json=>{
    dispatch({
       type:"addtask",
       payload:json
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you put the reducer here?

Comment: And add how you're passing the data to the reducer. And at what stage is it being changed. When it's received by the reducer? When the state is updated? When the value is passed to the a component? Need more detail and relevant code

Comment: even in the reducer the data is unchanged. but after the state is returned magic and now its bool

Comment: This is funny tbh....

Comment: Check the `typeof()` in each stages. In the DB, in the API route, in action creator and in reducer. Also you mentioned that the problem solved when the property name changed? I think the problem should be with your database. If you are using mongoose then most probably the problem is with mongoose model. Kind a logical error.

Comment: actually the data fetched from the API is of the correct format, the database is sql server